# Design Window Phone app screen size

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing app for Windows Phone. I have a Lumia 1320 and I noticed that apps on my device are wrongly seen so as many apps on the Store (like WhatsApp!)
`ScreenHeight` is wrong because, when task manager is open, I see a black border (especially if there is an `ApplicationBar`) on bottom and font size is bigger then the settled size on settings.
There is a plug-in or something in SDK for developing apps for 6" screen or there is something I miss?
Thank you all!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your problems are probably coming from your layout. You'll need to share more like a screenshot of your problem and the code to reproduce it, otherwise anyone trying to help you is likely just taking a shot in the dark. Oh, and is your profile pic meant for like a dating site? Most dev's won't care what ya look like with your shirt off amigo, just saying..

Answer (score 0):

You can change the resolution of the device that the UI designer uses by using the side bar (on the left usually).

Here's a screenshot for you.  When use correctly you can get a feel for what you app will look like on different phones.

[image]

Comment: I tried but I only have 3 types of device resolutions: 480x800 WVGA, 768x1280 WXGA and 720x1280 720p. How can I have all your choises? Is there something I miss in Visual Studio? Thanks a lot for answer!

Comment: Solved! Visual Studio needed un upgrade! Thank you!

Comment: Np, please mark it as a solution if it helped you viewed your app in multiple resolutions.